# Prove the inequality by induction: $3^n > n^3$ for $n\ge4$

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove the inequality by induction:

$3^n > n^3\ $ for $\ n \geq 4$

Edit:

1) Base case: $n=4$, $3^4>4^3, 81>64$
  2) Assume true for n=k: so $3^k>k^3$
3) Consider $(k+1)^3$, $(k+1)^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 +3k + 1 < k^3 + k^3 + k^3$, i.e. $(k+1)^3 < 3k^3$

For $k \geq 1$, $3(3^k) \geq 3(k^3)$, therefore $\ 3^{k+1}>3k^3>(k+1)^3$

And nowhere has the fact that $k \geq 4$ been used.., so I don't think this a complete, or at all a proof by induction of that inequality

Comment: The down-votes are probably because we value *showing your work* more than *showing an answer*.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180201/prove-by-mathematical-induction-that-forall-n-in-mathbbn-3n-n3) is an exact duplicate.

Comment: show us what have you try

Comment: $k\ge4$ is used in your base case. Instead, try comparing $3^k$ and $k^3$ for $k=3$.

Comment: $3^k = k^3 $ for $ \ k=3$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal So the inequality is false for $k=3$. This is where the condition $k\ge4$ is necessary.

Comment: "And nowhere has the fact that k≥4 been used" The condition $k\geqslant4$ is used to check the base case $k=4$. Note also that $k^3 + 3k^2 +3k + 1 < k^3 + k^3 + k^3$ requires $k\geqslant3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the inductive step, we can massage the terms until it works:
\begin{align*}
(k + 1)^3
&= k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \\
&< k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + (k) &\text{since } k \geq 4 > 1 \\
&= k^3 + 3k^2 + 4k \\
&\leq k^3 + 3k^2 + (k)k &\text{since } k \geq 4 \\
&= k^3 + 4k^2 \\
&\leq k^3 + (k)k^2 &\text{since } k \geq 4 \\
&= 2k^3 \\
&< 3k^3 \\
&< 3(3^k) &\text{by the induction hypothesis} \\
&= 3^{k + 1}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Very nice! I like it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the statement for the base case, $n=4$:
$$3^4 = 81 > 4^3 = 64$$
Now, assume it is true for $n$:
$$3^n > n^3$$

All you have to do now is make it true for $n+1$:
$$(n+1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 < 3^n + 3n^2 + 3n + 1 < 3^n + 2(3)^n = 3^{n+1}$$

Can you see why $3n^2 + 3n + 1 < 2(3)^n$ is true $\forall n \geq4 $ ?

Comment: hmmm.. I can't see why $3n^2+3n+1<2(3)^n$, but it is actually even true for $n=3$

Comment: Try to use induction!

Comment: Ok, so it is true for $\ n \geq 3 $

Comment: And then $\ 3^n(1+2) $ :) beautiful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to complete the induction step:

Assume that $3^n>n^3$ for some integer $n\ge4$.

Then $3^{n+1}=3(3^n)>3n^3$, and $3n^3>(n+1)^3$

since $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^3=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3\le\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)^3=\frac{125}{64}<3$ for $n\ge4$;

so $3^{n+1}>(n+1)^3$.